# https://www.example.com and https://example.com socket.io connection problem

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io

How do I get both https://example.com and https://www.example.com for endpoints to connect?
socket.io connect no problem at htttps://example.com
but not https://www.example.com

my server looks like

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://www.example.com:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
    credentials: true
  }});
```

and my client endpoint looks like this

```
const ENDPOINT = 'https://example.com/';
```

Comment: Configure your DNS to point both example.com and www.example.com to the same host IP address and then support both domains with your cors configuration. Then, either URL will go to the same host.

Comment: added origin to include both www.example.com and example.com but base on my client-side ENDPOINT if I go to the www version or vice versa it gets blocked 
An example of this would be if I put the ENDPOINT to example.com and go on my browser to example.com it works but not when I got to www.example.com because it gets blocked by cors, the same would happen in reverse if I changed it to www.example.com.

Comment: ``` 
const ENDPOINT = 'https://www.example.com/';
    const socket = io(ENDPOINT, {
      withCredentials: true,
      extraHeaders: {
        "my-custom-header": "my-custom-header"
      }
    });
    socket.on("data", data => {
      setResponse(data);
    }
```

Comment: setting end point to `${window.location.hostname}/` fixed my issue but I still don't know why the browser address have to match my endpoint for cors to not stop it

Comment: Apparently because you weren't doing your server-side CORs stuff correctly.  If the protocol, domain and port all match, then CORs is not an issue.  If the protocol, domain or port are different, then your server-side code has to permit the CORs access.  FYI, if you set `transports: ['websocket']` as an option when connection from the client, then it will go directly to a webSocket connection which is not limited by CORs at all.

Comment: Oh, now I see it.  Your custom header was probably blocking CORs and requiring pre-flight permission.  CORs has two levels, simple and not-simple.  When you add a custom header, you force CORs into the not-simple route where it requires preflight which is probably more than the built-in socketio cors features will handle.

Comment: @jfriend00 thx man! it was bugging me on why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your DNS to point both example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to the same host IP address and then support both domains with your cors configuration. Then, either URL will go to the same host.

You can avoid cors entirely if you configure socket.io to start immediately with a webSocket, not with the http polling that it usually starts with.  You can do that in the client by adding the `transports: ['websocket']` option to the client connect.

And, your custom header was probably blocking CORs and requiring pre-flight permission. CORs has two levels, simple and not-simple. When you add a custom header, you force CORs into the not-simple route where it requires preflight which is probably more than the built-in socketio cors features will handle.